# python pyquery import not working on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: python, macos, pyquery

I'm trying to import pyquery as I did hundreds on time before, and it's not working. It looks like related to the Mac OS Sierra. (module installed with pip and up-to-date)

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
```

And got an error on the namespacing

```
ImportError: cannot import name PyQuery
```

Any idea ? 
Thx !

Answer (score 0):

Finally found why. My file had the same name as my import... 
So the library import was overridden by the name of the .py file.